# QGIS raster calculator gives 'Nan'

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

With QGIS 2.14.3 I am attempting to convert a raster layer to a binary layer, using a certain threshold. With some layers I can use this formula in the Raster Calculator and get the expected output;

```
"raster@1" < 0.994 = 0 AND "raster@1" > 0.994 = 1
```

But when I try it with another layer the output is either all `nan` or all `0`'s. I've tried saving it in a different format (.img instead of .tif) as suggested in another answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195473/qgis-raster-calculator-difference-gives-nan-for-landsat-8-scene), but get the same result.

Is there a mistake I'm making with this?

Or an obvious reason it might give this output?

Or maybe the raster is just corrupted in some way?

(The imagery is the output from a long process, and confidential, so I can't share the actual file).

Comment: Could you try `"raster@1" >= 0.994`? Actually this should procure the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking an impossible question, `raster@1` cannot be less than 0.994 **AND** greater than 0.994 at the same time. I would change it to

```
"raster@1" < 0.994 = 0 OR "raster@1" >= 0.994 = 1
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand how the Raster Calculator works? Cells within the raster can have values of less than and greater than 0.994. I have used the formula as written above with `AND`, which gave the expected output.